# Como pasar datos con json

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, json

Necesito pasar de `PHP`  un `JSON`  a cada campo que le corresponda el valor, por el momento pruebo con el valor del `select` y se supones que debería ponerlo en el campo cédula. Adjunto el código

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.post("../php/llenar.php", function(data){
  $("#capitan").html(data);
 });
 $("#capitan").change(function(){
  
  alert($("#capitan").val());
  $.get("../php/modificar.php",{cedula: $("#capitan").val()},function(data){
   $("#cedula").val(data.cedula);
  },"json");
 });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "es">
<head>
 <meta charset = "UTF-8">
 <title id="usuario"></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/reg.css">
 <script src = "../js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src = "../js/modificar_Cap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <form  method= "post" class = "form-registro">
  <h2> Modificar capitanes</h2>
  <div class ="contenedor-input">
   <select name = "capitan" id = "capitan" class = "input-100">
   </select>
   <input type = "text" id = "cedula" name = "cedula" placeholder = "Cedula" class = "input-100" disabled = false/>
   <input type = "text" id = "nombre"  name = "nombre" placeholder = "Nombres" class = "input-48" disabled = false/>
   <input type = "text" id = "apellido" name = "apellido" placeholder = "Apellidos" class = "input-48" disabled = false/>
   <input type = "email" id = "mail" name = "mail" placeholder = "Correo electronico" class = "input-100" disabled = false/>
   <input type = "text" id = "user" name = "user" placeholder = "Usuario" class = "input-48" disabled = false/>
   <input type = "text" id = "pwd" name = "pwd" placeholder = "Contraseña" class = "input-48" disabled = false/>
   <input type = "text" id = "privilegio" name = "privilegio" placeholder = "Cedula" class = "input-100" disabled = false/>
   <input type = "button" value = " Modificar capitan" class = "btn-enviar" id = "btn-enviar" disabled = false/>
 
  </div>  
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
    $cedula = $_GET['cedula'];
    echo $cedula;
    echo json_encode(array("cedula"=>$cedula));
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En primer lugar elimine el prime echo del `PHP` *`echo $cedula;`* , solo debe imprimir el `json`

```
$cedula = $_GET['cedula'];
echo json_encode(array("cedula"=>$cedula));
```

Luego en su Jquery , debería quedar así , con el reemplazo del `ready` del `document` de una forma más actual . *Jquery3*. Ya que `$(document).ready(function(){` está declarado como obsoleto.

```
 $(function() {
     $("#capitan").change(function(){
        $.get("script.php",{cedula: $("#capitan").val()},function(data){
            $("#cedula").val(data.cedula);
        },"json");
     });
 });
```